Correct placement of significant correlations when displaying upper or lower half of matrix
I am using ggcorrplot to visualize a correlation matrix. I want to remove non-significant correlation values but keep the color of the matrix cell. I can do this when showing the full matrix. However, the values are no longer displayed in the proper position if I show only the lower or upper portions of the matrix. How can I get the values to display properly when showing only one-half of the correlation matrix?
Similar SO question here.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

# Make correlation coefficient matrix 
corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

# Make p-value matrix associated with the correlation coefficients
corr_p <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

# When full matrix is shown
ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE, p.mat = corr_p, sig.level = 1) +
  geom_text(
  aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = round(value, 1)),
  \(d) subset(d, pvalue < 0.05))



# When only lower matrix is shown
ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE, p.mat = corr_p, sig.level = 1, type = 'lower') +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = round(value, 1)),
    \(d) subset(d, pvalue < 0.05))



# When only upper matrix is shown
ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE, p.mat = corr_p, sig.level = 1, type = 'upper') +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = round(value, 1)),
    \(d) subset(d, pvalue < 0.05))


Created on 2024-05-17 with reprex v2.1.0

EDIT : Here's another option to fulfill the needs of the OP :
### Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(dplyr)

### Make correlation coefficient matrix 
corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

### Make p-value matrix associated with the correlation coefficients
corr_p <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

### Create and store the graph
k=ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE, p.mat = corr_p, sig.level = 1) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = round(value, 1)),
    \(d) subset(d, pvalue < 0.05))

### Store the graph into a ggplot object you can modify
modify=ggplot_build(k)

### Transform the ggplot object
### First, we remove the data related to the upper part of the graph
modify$data[[3]]=modify$data[[3]] %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(up_low=case_when(y>x~"haut",
                          y<x~"bas",.default = "cor"),.before = 1) %>%
  filter(up_low=="bas") %>% 
  select(-up_low) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

### Then, we colour the upper part and the correlation diagonal in white
modify$data[[1]]=modify$data[[1]]%>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(up_low=case_when(y>x~"haut",
                          y<x~"bas",.default = "cor"),.before = 1) %>% 
  mutate(fill=case_when(up_low=="cor"~"#FFFFFF",
                        up_low=="haut"~"#FFFFFF",.default = fill)) %>% 
  select(-up_low) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

### We export the result with ggplot_table and display it properly with grid 
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(modify))

Output :


Original answer :
A possible workaround is to replace values in your p-values matrix :
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(purrr)

# Make correlation coefficient matrix 
corr <- round(cor(mtcars),1)

# Make p-value matrix associated with the correlation coefficients
corr_p <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

### Modify the corr_p matrix
### p-values of the lower portion will be replaced by 1
f=dim(corr_p)[1]
walk(.x = 1:(f-1),.f = ~{corr_p[(.x+1):f,.x]<<-1})

### Create the graph
ggcorrplot(corr, lab = FALSE, p.mat = corr_p, sig.level = 1) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, label = round(value, 1)),
    \(d) subset(d, pvalue < 0.05))

Output :


this is close but the goal is to only show the upper or lower half of the matrix, not the full matrix. I tried your answer including type = 'lower' and it did not include the values of the significant correlations on the matrix.

OK. I've provided a workaround in my original post.

How could I store the figure from grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(modify))? Currently when I try p1 <- grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(modify)) it returns a NULL value.

Save the ggplot_gtable(modify) into an object to store the figure. Export it by using ggsave(stored_object,filename=...,device=...,). Or display it first with grid.draw(stored_object) then export it immediately with ggsave(filename=...,device=...,).

For anyone else who may come across this question. The ggcorrplot function can be modified to achieve what the question was asking (i.e., remove insig values but keep their color).
Here are the modifications and an example of their usage.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)

# First need to define some helper functions ----
# Helper function to remove the diagonal elements of a matrix
.remove_diag <- function(mat) {
  diag(mat) <- NA
  return(mat)
}

# Helper function to order the correlation matrix using hierarchical clustering
.hc_cormat_order <- function(corr, hc.method = "complete") {
  dist <- as.dist((1 - corr) / 2)
  hc <- hclust(dist, method = hc.method)
  return(hc$order)
}

# Helper function to get the lower triangular part of the matrix
.get_lower_tri <- function(mat, show.diag = FALSE) {
  mat[upper.tri(mat, diag = !show.diag)] <- NA
  return(mat)
}

# Helper function to get the upper triangular part of the matrix
.get_upper_tri <- function(mat, show.diag = FALSE) {
  mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = !show.diag)] <- NA
  return(mat)
}

# Second, modify the ggcorrplot function ----
# Modified ggcorrplot function
modified_ggcorrplot <- function (corr, method = c("square", "circle"), type = c("full", 
                                                                                "lower", "upper"), ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_minimal, title = "", 
                                 show.legend = TRUE, legend.title = "Corr", show.diag = NULL, 
                                 colors = c("blue", "white", "red"), outline.color = "gray", 
                                 hc.order = FALSE, hc.method = "complete", lab = FALSE, lab_col = "black", 
                                 lab_size = 4, p.mat = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, insig = c("pch", 
                                                                                         "blank"), pch = 4, pch.col = "black", pch.cex = 5, tl.cex = 12, 
                                 tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45, digits = 2, as.is = FALSE) 
{
  type <- match.arg(type)
  method <- match.arg(method)
  insig <- match.arg(insig)
  if (is.null(show.diag)) {
    if (type == "full") {
      show.diag <- TRUE
    }
    else {
      show.diag <- FALSE
    }
  }
  if (inherits(corr, "cor_mat")) {
    cor.mat <- corr
    corr <- .tibble_to_matrix(cor.mat)
    p.mat <- .tibble_to_matrix(attr(cor.mat, "pvalue"))
  }
  if (!is.matrix(corr) & !is.data.frame(corr)) {
    stop("Need a matrix or data frame!")
  }
  corr <- as.matrix(corr)
  corr <- base::round(x = corr, digits = digits)
  if (hc.order) {
    ord <- .hc_cormat_order(corr, hc.method = hc.method)
    corr <- corr[ord, ord]
    if (!is.null(p.mat)) {
      p.mat <- p.mat[ord, ord]
      p.mat <- base::round(x = p.mat, digits = digits)
    }
  }
  if (!show.diag) {
    corr <- .remove_diag(corr)
    p.mat <- .remove_diag(p.mat)
  }
  if (type == "lower") {
    corr <- .get_lower_tri(corr, show.diag)
    p.mat <- .get_lower_tri(p.mat, show.diag)
  }
  else if (type == "upper") {
    corr <- .get_upper_tri(corr, show.diag)
    p.mat <- .get_upper_tri(p.mat, show.diag)
  }
  corr <- reshape2::melt(corr, na.rm = TRUE, as.is = as.is)
  colnames(corr) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "value")
  corr$pvalue <- rep(NA, nrow(corr))
  corr$signif <- rep(NA, nrow(corr))
  if (!is.null(p.mat)) {
    p.mat <- reshape2::melt(p.mat, na.rm = TRUE)
    corr$coef <- corr$value
    corr$pvalue <- p.mat$value
    corr$signif <- as.numeric(p.mat$value <= sig.level)
    p.mat <- subset(p.mat, p.mat$value > sig.level)
  }
  corr$abs_corr <- abs(corr$value) * 10
  p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = corr, mapping = ggplot2::aes_string(x = "Var1", 
                                                                  y = "Var2", fill = "value"))
  if (method == "square") {
    p <- p + ggplot2::geom_tile(color = outline.color)
  }
  else if (method == "circle") {
    p <- p + ggplot2::geom_point(color = outline.color, 
                                 shape = 21, ggplot2::aes_string(size = "abs_corr")) + 
      ggplot2::scale_size(range = c(4, 10)) + ggplot2::guides(size = "none")
  }
  p <- p + ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient2(low = colors[1], 
                                         high = colors[3], mid = colors[2], midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1, 
                                                                                                    1), space = "Lab", name = legend.title)
  if (class(ggtheme)[[1]] == "function") {
    p <- p + ggtheme()
  }
  else if (class(ggtheme)[[1]] == "theme") {
    p <- p + ggtheme
  }
  p <- p + ggplot2::theme(axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(angle = tl.srt, 
                                                              vjust = 1, size = tl.cex, hjust = 1), axis.text.y = ggplot2::element_text(size = tl.cex)) + 
    ggplot2::coord_fixed()
  label <- round(x = corr[, "value"], digits = digits)
  if (!is.null(p.mat) & insig == "blank") {
    ns <- corr$pvalue > sig.level
    if (sum(ns) > 0) 
      label[ns] <- ""
  }
  if (lab) {
    p <- p + ggplot2::geom_text(mapping = ggplot2::aes_string(x = "Var1", 
                                                              y = "Var2"), label = label, color = lab_col, size = lab_size)
  }
  if (!is.null(p.mat) & insig == "pch") {
    p <- p + ggplot2::geom_point(data = p.mat, mapping = ggplot2::aes_string(x = "Var1", 
                                                                             y = "Var2"), shape = pch, size = pch.cex, color = pch.col)
  }
  if (title != "") {
    p <- p + ggplot2::ggtitle(title)
  }
  if (!show.legend) {
    p <- p + ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none")
  }
  p
}

# Example usage
corr_matrix <- round(cor(mtcars),1)
p.mat <- cor_pmat(mtcars)
modified_ggcorrplot(corr_matrix,
                    p.mat = p.mat,
                    lab = TRUE,
                    insig = "blank",
                    type = 'lower',
                    digits = 1,
                    ggtheme = theme_bw) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
#> Warning: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0.
#> ℹ Please use tidy evaluation idioms with `aes()`.
#> ℹ See also `vignette("ggplot2-in-packages")` for more information.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


Created on 2024-05-20 with reprex v2.1.0
